# Order of $\alpha=(124)(5439)(328)(1378542)\in S_{10}$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I know that the order of an element in a symmetric group is given by $\text{lcm}(a,b)$ where a and b are the length of the cycle. But not sure what to do with more then 2  cycles.

Comment: Take the lcm of all the cycle lengths.

Comment: Note; this isn't a standard cycle presentation, since $3$ appears in multiple "cycles".  You'll need to multiply these together and sort out the actual cycles.

Comment: Yes, @lulu is right; the lcm computation only applies when the element has been written as a product of *disjoint* cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By direct computation, and reading left to right,  the product of the permutations you have written decomposes into disjoint cycles as:  $$
(1 5 2) (3 9 4) (7 8) (6)$$

Two of these have length $3$, the third has length $2$ (the fixed point has length $1$ of course), and since these commute, the order of this product is $6$.
'

Note:  as remarked in the comments, the problem says this is taking place in $S_{10}$, so we have to include $X=10$ in the cycles (using Roman Numerals since, say, writing $(10)$ is ambiguous).  Thus the disjoint cycle representation should have been $$(1 5 2) (3 9 4) (7 8) (6) (X)$$  It is also standard to simply omit fixed points, and write $$(1 5 2) (3 9 4) (7 8)$$

This convention comes in handy with permutations on infinite sets which fix all but finitely many elements. To be sure, none of this changes the calculation of the order.

Comment: How did you do this? When I try to decompose into disjoint cycles I start with $a_1=1$, take $\alpha(1)=a_2$ and I get a cycle of $(148)$ then taking $b_1=2$ I get a second cycle of $(237)$ at which point I get stuck because taking $\alpha(7)$ gives me 4 so my cycles aren't disjoint anymore.

Comment: Just go number by number.  Let's start with $1$.  Reading from left to right we see $1\mapsto 2\mapsto 5$.  Thus $1\to 5$.  And so on.  Once you have the full permutation, the disjoint cycles are apparent.

Comment: Since the title says it's an element of $S_{10}$, I guess it should be $(152)(394)(78)(6)(T)$, where $T$ stands for ten.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  True.  Or just omit both fixed points, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

It is still the $\DeclareMathOperator{lcm}{lcm} \lcm$, but this time the $\lcm(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k)$ where $a_1, \dots a_k$ are the lengths of all disjoint cycles of $\alpha$.

Note that, in general, the $\lcm$ of the cycle lengths does **not** yield the order of $\alpha$ if those cycles have common elements: $\iota = (1,2,3)(1,3,2)$ but $\DeclareMathOperator{ord}{ord} \ord(\iota) = 1$

Comment: What does $ord$ mean?

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{ord}{ord} \ord(\alpha)$ is just the order of $\alpha$

Comment: @AColoredReptile Probably “order” since that’s what your question is about per your title